# For a JSON usecase how to add a field to a PDXInstance

Tags: gemfire, geode

A customer of mine is storing JSON documents into GemFire and would like to add fields to existing JSON documents by manipulating the PDXInstance to save unnecessary serialization costs. I was looking at the API and it does not look like there is a way today to add a field by using the PDXInstance. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to add a field to a PdxInstance. There is a PDXInstanceFactory, but that only lets you build entirely new objects.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Ideally, Would it make sense for the WritablePDXInstance to have a method to add a new field?